# Existe a palavra "'trambos'"?

Tags: expressões, regionalismo

Eu já a falei várias vezes e já ouvi pessoas falando, também. Mas, pelo que vi, não é uma palavra real, pois não a vi em nenhum dicionário.

Essa palavra é o equivalente de "ambos" para três.

Será que "trambos" é um regionalismo de São Bernardo do campo, SP? Se eu a falar, serei entendido?

Exemplo:

> "trambas" as ideias são boas, mas prefiro a primeira.
>
> — Quando será que eles chegam? — Acho que "trambos" estão parados, no tráfego.

Comment: Se é talvez um regionalismo, de onde seria?

Comment: @ANeves, moro em Brasil, São Paulo, São Bernardo do Campo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olá!

Eu moro no Brasil desde que nasci e nunca ouvi a palavra "trambos". Ao pesquisar em alguns dicionários de lingua portuguesa em casa, também não encontrei. Portanto, acredito que seja uma gíria ou expressão do lugar onde você mora e, baseado nisso, você não será compreendido na maioria dos países que falam a lingua portuguesa.

Comment: +1 Jamais tinha ouvido.

Comment: Obrigado, @Chanp.